# Images that are bigger than 50 MB have smaller thumbnails

Tags: nautilus, 22.10

In Ubuntu 22.10, images that are bigger than 50 MB are displayed in smaller thumbnails. Is there some option in `dconf` to change that number?

[image]

This is the only option I could find. But it's for *displaying* thumbnails of a certain size; it doesn't control the *size* of thumbnails that are of a certain size:

[image]